# Is there any point to the Interplanetary Shuttle in Frontier:Elite II?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, frontier-elite-2

I've just gone back to Frontier: Elite II using DOSBox and it reminded me of a question that I had when I first played the game: what is the point of the Interplanetary Shuttle? You can buy it, but you can't replace the drive or anything. And as far as I can tell you can't own more than one ship. So... what's the point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passenger or freight service from surface to orbit. But I sincerely doubt you'll ever be that destitute.

You'll find that a great many of the ships that can be bought really aren't that useful for a single lone pilot; they're available for purchase mainly because *all* ships are. And, of course, as ever with Elite 1 or 2 your fun is where you find it.

Comment: Are the Lynx Bulk Carrier and Long Range Cruiser also purchasable? Piloting either one used to be my biggest dream but I only saw them uselessly floating around, never having a "SALE" sign on them.

Comment: Are there ads on the bulletin board that ask for passage from planet to orbit?

Comment: Not usually, but pretty much everything is procedurally generated, so it's possible.